# How to apply for loop function into crosstab making in R

Tags: r, for-loop, crosstab

```r
test1 <- structure(list(weight = c(0.2158, 0.799, 0.611, 0.4969, 0.3469, 
1.0107, 0.6946, 0.9415, 1.4008, 0.6192), Q2_1 = structure(c(4, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You or someone in your family will get sick with COVID-19", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Q2_2 = structure(c(3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You might experience serious side effects from the COVID-19 vaccine", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), group = c("E", "E", "E", "D", "E", "E", "D", "E", 
"D", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is one of the goal crosstabs I would like to make.

```
library(pollster)
crosstab(df = test1 , x = Q2_1, y = group, weight = weight,pct_type = "column")
```

| Q2_1 | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Somewhat worried | 19.16831 | 47.79164 |
| Not too worried | 80.83169 | 29.87610 |
| Not at all worried | 0.00000 | 22.33226 |
| n | 2.59230 | 4.54410 |

I'm trying to make multiple crosstabs by using a loop function.

```
for (i in colnames(test1)[2]) {
  table1 <- crosstab(df = test1, x = i, y = group, weight = weight,pct_type = "column")
  print(table1)
}
```

| i | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q2_1 | 100.0000 | 100.0000 |
| n | 2.5923 | 4.5441 |

I've got this wrong crosstab the column name "Q2_1" move to the first row and create a column called "i". My goal is to create multiple crosstabs from columns such as Q2_1, Q2_2. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is the first time using stack overflow. Hope the formatting is clear and correct.

Comment: Please read this about creating a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot copy code from an image. Paste your data into your question using `dput(test1)`, code you've tried, and error messages you're getting.

Comment: 1. Don't add data and/or code as images. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2) Which package is function `crosstab` from? Include all the non base R libraries that you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that and create another question.

Comment: @caesar please edit this question rather than making a new one. Thanks.

Comment: I had edited it. I hope it looks better now!

Comment: I think you are using the `pollster` package. You should include this information in your question as Ronak Shah stated before.

Comment: I had added the package I used in my question. My question was solved. Thanks to all who responded and answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```r
library(pollster)
library(rlang)

for (i in colnames(test1)[2:3]) {
  table <- crosstab(
    df = test1, 
    x = !!sym(i), 
    y = group, 
    weight = weight, 
    pct_type = "column")
  print(table)
}
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Q2_1                   D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8 
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9 
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3 
4 n                   2.59  4.54

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Q2_2                   D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried    0    34.2 
2 Not too worried    54.0  34.6 
3 Not at all worried 46.0  31.2 
4 n                   2.59  4.54
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.

Comment: Hi. It returns two tables but I want to save then in one table since they have the same number of rows. It's important for saving the table in excel, for instance. Do you have ideas how I could do this?

Comment: @Laura this depends on your expected output. I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: In fact, I already did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837731/loop-to-output-multiple-crosstables-but-add-tables-by-columns-to-make-one-table