# Loop to output multiple crosstables but add tables by columns to make one table in R

Tags: r

I have a loop that can create multiple cross tables for one column but instead of having them printed in sequence I need them to be added by column, just like when we use `cbind()`, because the number of rows is the same (since crosstabs are of one column against other columns in df).

Here is an example of the data from an existing question: [How to apply for loop function into crosstab making in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578189/how-to-apply-for-loop-function-into-crosstab-making-in-r)

```
test1 <- structure(list(weight = c(0.2158, 0.799, 0.611, 0.4969, 0.3469, 
1.0107, 0.6946, 0.9415, 1.4008, 0.6192), Q2_1 = structure(c(4, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You or someone in your family will get sick with COVID-19", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Q2_2 = structure(c(3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You might experience serious side effects from the COVID-19 vaccine", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), group = c("E", "E", "E", "D", "E", "E", "D", "E", 
"D", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the function that outputs multiple crosstabs but in sequence:

```
library(pollster)
library(rlang)

for (i in colnames(test1)[2:3]) {
  table <- crosstab(
    df = test1, 
    x = !!sym(i), 
    y = group, 
    weight = weight, 
    pct_type = "column")
  print(table)
}

 Q2_1                   D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8 
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9 
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3 
4 n                   2.59  4.54
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Q2_2                   D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried    0    34.2 
2 Not too worried    54.0  34.6 
3 Not at all worried 46.0  31.2 
4 n                   2.59  4.54
```

Instead of printing them in sequence I want them in a single table attached to each other by column like what the command `cbind()` does so instead of two tabled I will have one table with the same rows and all columns combined from two crosstabs. Here is an example of an expected output:

```
                      D     E       D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8     0    34.2
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9    54.0  34.6
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3    46.0  31.2
4 n                   2.59  4.54   2.59  4.54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output uses the same names for different columns. This is usally a bad idea, so you probably should adjust the column names.

So in your case you could use one of the following ways:

```r
my_list <- list()

for (i in colnames(test1)[2:3]) {
  my_list[[i]] <- crosstab(
    df = test1, 
    x = !!sym(i), 
    y = group, 
    weight = weight, 
    pct_type = "column")
  
  colnames(my_list[[i]])[1] <- "index"
  
}
```

First we store the crosstab results in a `list` and assign a constant column name for the first column.

Now you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(my_list)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  index...1          D...2 E...3 index...4          D...5 E...6
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8  Somewhat worried    0    34.2 
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9  Not too worried    54.0  34.6 
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3  Not at all worried 46.0  31.2 
4 n                   2.59  4.54 n                   2.59  4.54
```

As you can see, the column names changed to make them unique. You can skip this by using the `.name_repair = "minimal"` argument. This returns

```r
# > bind_cols(my_list, .name_repair = "minimal")
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  index                  D     E index                  D     E
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8  Somewhat worried    0    34.2 
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9  Not too worried    54.0  34.6 
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3  Not at all worried 46.0  31.2 
4 n                   2.59  4.54 n                   2.59  4.54
```

Another option uses the `purrr` package combined with `left_join`

```r
my_list %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "index")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  index                D.x   E.x   D.y   E.y
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Somewhat worried   19.2  47.8   0    34.2 
2 Not too worried    80.8  29.9  54.0  34.6 
3 Not at all worried  0    22.3  46.0  31.2 
4 n                   2.59  4.54  2.59  4.54
```

You can adjust the column names via `left_join`s `.suffix` argument. The default values are `x` and `y` resulting in `D.x` and `D.y`.